# Rails: accept first search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using [MetaSearch](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/) in a Rails 3 project although I imagine the search method doesn't really matter that much.

My controller looks like this:

```
  def index
    @search = Household.search(params[:search])
    @households = @search.all
  end
```

If there is only a single search result, I want to go directly to the "show" action for that item, otherwise go to the "index" action. (Right now everything goes to the "index" action, which adds another step for the user).

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add something like

```
if @households.count == 1
redirect_to household_path(@households.first)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
def index
  @search = Household.search(params[:search])
  @households = @search.all
  if @households.size == 1
    redirect_to @households.first
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry Jits, I would accept your answer too, since it's pretty much the same as Paul's.  He has less reputation, so I went with his answer.  Thanks though.